# Test class not picking up contact at account related to opp

Tags: apex, soql, unit-test

I have an opportunity class ext that has:

```
List<Contact> relatedContacts = [SELECT Id, account.id, firstName, lastName, email, 
                                        Title, account.name, account.website
                                   FROM Contact WHERE account.id = :opp.account.id];
```

and in my test class I am doing:

```
//Create Account
Account ac = new Account (name='acme');
ac.website = 'www.test.com';
insert ac;

//Create Contact
Contact ctc = new Contact (lastname='lastName');
ctc.firstName = 'justin';

ctc.email = 'test@test.com';
ctc.account = ac;
insert ctc;

//Create Opportunity
Opportunity op = new Opportunity (name='test opp');
op.account = ac;
op.stageName = '0 - MQL';
op.closedate = date.newInstance(1987, 12, 17);
insert op;
```

but for some reason the contact is not being selected in my SOQL call.

any ideas?

Comment: in your test class, where is your controller extension being instantiated ?  (Also: you can use `accountId` field rather than `account.id`)

Comment: We need to see how you get `opp`.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!

I needed to set account = ac and accountid = ac.id on the contact and opportunity objects

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful.  - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/46545)

Comment: Sorry, I cant figure out how to mark a comment as an answer.